# Dataframe index with isclose function

Tags: dataframe, indexing, boolean

I have a dataframe with numerical values between 0 and 1.  I am trying to create simple summary statistics (manually).  I when using boolean I can get the index but when I try to use math.isclose the function does not work and gives an error.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0,.05,0.74,0.76,1], 'col2': [0, 
             0.05,0.5, 0.75,1], 'x1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'x2': 
             [5,6,7,8,9]})
result75 = df1.index[round(df1['col2'],2) == 0.75].tolist()
value75 = df1['x2'][result75]
print(value75.mean())
```

This will give the correct result but occasionally the value result is NAN so I tried:

```
    result75 = df1.index[math.isclose(round(df1['col2'],2), 0.75, abs_tol = 0.011)].tolist()
    value75 = df1['x2'][result75]
    print(value75.mean())
```

This results in the following error message:

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Both are type "bool" so not sure what is going wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
rows_meeting_condition = df1[(df1['col2'] > 0.74) & (df1['col2'] < 0.76)]
print(rows_meeting_condition['x2'].mean())
```